# Building SFML on Fedora 24 linking error: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, sfml, dynamic-linking

I have been trying to get SFML working on Fedora 24 for a few days now and I can't seem to get it to work. The program compiles and links fine, but when I try to run the compiled program I get this error:

```
./sfml-app: error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know that the files are there since they are all located in the /usr/lib directory:

```
ls /usr/lib | grep sfml
libsfml-audio-d.so
libsfml-audio-d.so.2.4
libsfml-audio-d.so.2.4.0
libsfml-graphics-d.so
libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.4
libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.4.0
libsfml-network-d.so
libsfml-network-d.so.2.4
libsfml-network-d.so.2.4.0
libsfml-system-d.so
libsfml-system-d.so.2.4
libsfml-system-d.so.2.4.0
libsfml-window-d.so
libsfml-window-d.so.2.4
libsfml-window-d.so.2.4.0
```

I think the problem is that it is looking for libsfml-graphics.so.2.4 but the file is actually named libsfml-graphics**-d**.so.2.4. The -d is in the actual file name for some reason. I tried making a link to the file without the -d but it still did not work.

I built SFML myself with CMake and `make` then installed it using `make install`.

When I run ldconfig -p | grep sfml I get this:

```
libsfml-window-d.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-window-d.so.2.4
libsfml-window-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-window-d.so
libsfml-system-d.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-system-d.so.2.4
libsfml-system-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-system-d.so
libsfml-network-d.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-network-d.so.2.4
libsfml-network-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-network-d.so
libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.4
libsfml-graphics-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so
libsfml-audio-d.so.2.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-audio-d.so.2.4
libsfml-audio-d.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libsfml-audio-d.so
```

Any help with getting this working will be much appreciated. :)

Edit:
I got it working downloading the official fedora SFML package. I guess the first time I installed it I forgot to also install the SFML-devel package.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the official version that comes with the distro?

Comment: I was using that one originally but it was giving me this error: ./sfml-app: symbol lookup error: /lib/libsfml-graphics.so.2.4: undefined symbol: __cpu_model which is what is happening now that I tried jesper's solution below

Comment: Did you check your /usr/lib64 folder? Is it a 64bit install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '-d' files are the debug versions of the library (if I remember SFML's naming convention correctly). You seem to be missing the non-debug version.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks! But now I have a new problem. It gives me an error saying: ./sfml-app: symbol lookup error: /lib/libsfml-graphics.so.2.4: undefined symbol: __cpu_model

Comment: @JRud52 See here: http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=20638.0

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you, this patch worked for me on Fedora 25 with gcc 6.3.1.